# Swarm client does not found Jenkins controller

Tags: java, jenkins

Just updating jenkins to 2.321 and swarm plugin 3.28 and swarm-client is 3.9.

When i start swarm-client i got

```
# java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=./logging.properties -jar /home/jenkins/swarm- 
 client.jar -executors 3 -username **** -password **** -name slave-1 -disableClientsUniqueId -master http://jenkinshost/jenkins -fsroot /home/jenkins
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client main
INFO: Client.main invoked with: [-executors 3 -username **** -password **** -name slave-1 -disableClientsUniqueId -master http://jenkinshost/jenkins -fsroot /home/jenkins]
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient <init>
CONFIG: SwarmClient constructed with hudson.plugins.swarm.Options@511d50c0
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Discovering Jenkins master
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient discoverFromMasterUrl
CONFIG: discoverFromMasterUrl() invoked
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient discoverFromMasterUrl
CONFIG: Connecting to http://jenkinshost/jenkins/ to configure swarm client.
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient createHttpClient
FINE: createHttpClient() invoked
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient createHttpClient
FINE: Setting HttpClient credentials based on options passed
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient discoverFromMasterUrl
SEVERE: Failed to fetch swarm information from Jenkins, plugin not installed?
Nov 24, 2021 10:17:12 AM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
SEVERE: RetryException occurred
hudson.plugins.swarm.RetryException: Failed to fetch swarm information from Jenkins, plugin not installed?
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient.discoverFromMasterUrl(SwarmClient.java:229)
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.run(Client.java:115)
    at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.main(Client.java:88)
```

Using curl i got proper response from http://jenkinshost/jenkins/ but http://jenkinshost/jenkins/plugin/swarm/slaveInfo gives 404

Any ideas?

Comment: I clone https://github.com/jenkinsci/swarm-plugin and build new swarm-client from master and it seems work ok.

Comment: same problem, but no solution working, still 404